# Is the diameter of intersection of a set with a sphere of radius $r$ a measurable function of $r$?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, lebesgue-measure

I have to face to following problem: let $X$ be a separable metric space and $x_0 \in X$ fixed.

Consider an open bounded set $A \subset X$.

I want to know if the function $f: [0, \infty) \mapsto [0, \infty)$ bellow is measurable:

$$f(r) = \operatorname{diam}[ S(x_0, r) \cap A ]$$

with $S(x_0,r) = \{x \in X: d(x,x_0)=r\}$.

Of course, I'd say it is, but how to show?
I don't know what to say about the inverse image sets of $f$.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Let's take $X$ to be the union of $[-1,0]$ and a nonmeasurable subset of $(0,1]$
(with the usual metric of $\mathbb R$, this is a separable metric space), $x_0 = 0$, and $A = X$.  Then $S(0,r)$ is either
$\{-r\}$ or $\{-r,r\}$ depending on whether or not $r \in X$, and correspondingly
$f(r) = 0$ or $2r$.  Since $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{0\} \cup X$, the function $f$ is not measurable.

Comment: That's a pity! I really needed $f$ to be measurable, at least.

One question: the fact that $X$ is an union of a measurable set with a nonmeasurable set makes it nonmeasurable?

Comment: I ask it because with this nonmeasurable set $E \subset (0,1]$, we can write $(0,1]$ as union of $E$ and his complement in $(0,1]$. And yet, the union is measurable.

Comment: $X$ is nonmeasurable because its intersection with the measurable set $(0,1]$ is nonmeasurable (the intersection of two measurable sets would be measurable).

Comment: For a complete metric space, $f$ would be measurable.

Comment: I don't know how to justify it in this case either.

Did you put in X the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ induced in $X$ as topological subspace?

Comment: Sorry, on second thought I think you might want it to be $\sigma$-compact (i.e. the union of countably many compact sets) rather than complete.  In that case $f$ is the supremum of countably many upper semicontinuous functions.

Comment: Well, since $f$ is nonmeasurable, I'll have to use Riemman upper integral. But in this case, I'll have to prove that Monotone Convervence Theorem still holds.

Thank you, man.